# Amazon S3 image, cannot be saved using html5 canvas, gives Tainted Canvases Error

Tags: html, canvas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

Well having problems using canvas to save image in both(Chrome,Firefox and Safari),

When I load a hosted image in html5 canvas, an error is shown in canvas (though only in Chome not Firefox), the image is from **Amazon S3** server:

`Image from origin 'https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9015' is therefore not allowed access.`

And when I try to save the canvas as image,

`Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.`

Well yes, I have set the CORS config,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

and

```
img.crossOrigin = 'something'
```

and I looked at [Respond Proxy Js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/tree/cross-domain), but could not understand how to use it.

I have looked through a lot of SO posts and other references but can't solve the problem.Can anyone provide me with any solution.

@Update: if i change the line `<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>` => `<AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:9015</AllowedOrigin>`, the solutions seems to allow Chrome to save the canvas Image, but the problem is still persistent in Firefox and Safari

Comment: show ALL of your code related to the img element: how it is created, when the crossOrigin property is set, when the src attribute is set, etc.  all of this is important in order to solve your problem

Comment: @Ray sorry for the late reply, different time-zones, heres my
http://jsfiddle.net/mandeeeep/Z8cBC/4/

Answer (score -1):

In firefox and IE your  need to look like

```
<img src="https://platform3-preit-image.s3.amazonaws.com/components/fireside2.png" crossOrigin="anonymous" class="draggable-image" />
```

In chrome it need to be without `crossOrigin`. If you include `crossOrigin` attribute in chrome it will fail.

```
<img src="https://platform3-preit-image.s3.amazonaws.com/components/fireside2.png" class="draggable-image" />
```

So basically you need to render two different html output base on browser.

Comment: In Firefox, I am not having any problems weather I use `crossOrigin="anonymous"` or not though I still can't save the canvas img, and in case of chrome even if I remove the attr the error is still persistent. You could check out my fiddle.

Comment: Original question is about canvas, not html.

Comment: downvoted as when i do canvas.imageUrl it gives that tainted error on both firefox and chrome , though image shows on ui